# Recover .raw files using c

Tags: c

I am trying to read a .raw file and recover JPG files and then create 50 of them. I can compile, but my output does not display, though i do have all 50 jpg files.

I have succesfully printed 50 jpg photos with names from 000.jpg to 049.jpg. When trying to open them, I get this message:

Error interpreting JPEG image file (Improper call to JPEG library in state 201)

I hopefully am correctly making sure that files are closed before i open another one

Here is my code:

```
#define JPEG1 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0
#define JPEG2 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe1
#define BLOCK 512

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// long enough to store the name of a jpeg file
char jpeg_name[4];

// where we are going to store our data
BYTE buffer[512];

// open the picture file  
FILE* file = fopen("card.raw", "r");

// error checking
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("File could not be opened");
    return 2;
}

// how many jpegs we have at any one time
int jpeg_num = 0;

// check if we're open
int open = 0;

// the outfile we will use for all jpeg files
FILE* jpeg = NULL;

// do this until we can't come up with a full 512, fread returns what it has succesfully      read
// dont need to use address operator for image_data because its an array
while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), BLOCK, file) == BLOCK)
{
    // this will help us count and name files
    int i = 0;

    // if this the begenning of a jpeg file?
    if ((buffer[0] ==  0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff) && (buffer[3] ==   0xe0 || buffer[3] == 0xe1))
    {
        // is there a jpeg file already open?
        //if (fopen("jpeg_name", "r") != NULL)
        if(open == 1)
        {
            fclose(jpeg);
            open = 0;
        }

        // name the jpegs we find
        sprintf(jpeg_name, "%03d.jpg", jpeg_num+i);

        // open the jpeg from sprintf
        jpeg = fopen(jpeg_name, "w");
        open = 1;

        // error checking
        if (jpeg == NULL)
        {
            printf("JPEG file could not be created");
            return 1;
        }    

        // write to our file
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), BLOCK, jpeg);

        // increment counter
        i++;
        jpeg_num += 1;            

    }


}
if(jpeg)
{
  fclose(jpeg);
}
fclose(file);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: `jpeg_name` only has 4 characters, but your `sprintf()` will try to write at least 8, e.g. `001.jpg` plus the null byte.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see.

- The size of the jpeg_name variable is 3 but you are writing 8 bytes into it: 001.jpg(null)
- You are reading everything but only writing the first block of each JPEG style file (assuming your header is correct).
- Are you quite sure the binary string 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0 will not occur in the random binary inside a JPEG?

Comment: Okay, so I've changed char jpeg_name[3]; to char jpeg_name[8], but I do not know how to correct my fwrite statement. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same programming assignment. One thing I noticed in the code is that the fourth byte of a jpeg can range from 0xe0 to 0xef. In your code I only see 
buffer[3] ==   0xe0 || buffer[3] == 0xe1